# Error NU5049 The pack command for SDK-style projects is not supported

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

My solution contains Framework 4.8 projects, .Net Standard 2.1 projects and .net6 projects. It has been running without problems for weeks.

Today build pipeline has started to fail with the error

> ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Error NU5049: The pack command for SDK-style projects is not supported, use
> dotnet pack or msbuild -t:pack to pack this project instead. You can
> override this behavior by setting the
> ‘NUGET_ENABLE_LEGACY_CSPROJ_PACK’ environment variable to ‘true’.
> Error NU5000: Failed to build package.

I tried editing the YAML to change the command from pack to dotnet pack but I get a value is not accepted error.

[image: Error]

[Update]

I am trying to see exactly how I correct the syntax.
I tried typing dotnet into the tasks bar and get the following
[image: choices]

I tried .Net Core but the command it inserts has -task:DotNetCoreCLI@2
which also did not work.

What is the YAML for dotnet pack ?

My YAML is as follows

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  Major: '2'
  Minor: '0'
  Patch: '0'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>=4.3.0'
    checkLatest: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'WinFormsCoreMain\nuget.config'
    patchVersion: '$(Patch)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: '$(Major)'
    minorVersion: '$(Minor)'
```

I changed the restore command to

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'WinFormsCoreMain\nuget.config'
    patchVersion: '$(Patch)'
```

This now gives an error

> ##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not
> dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet
> build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate
> such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use
> Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk
> version(<=3) to build
> ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
> ##[error]An error occurred while trying to pack the files.

> ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
> ##[error]Packages failed to restore
> Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version
> which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for
> your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking
> behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about
> the breaking changes here:
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn
> about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here:
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting

I thought I might try clicking New Pipeline to see what DevOps wanted but I git a 503 error.

[image: 503]

However when I click "View our service status updates" there are no problems reported.

[Update]

Now I am able to create a new pipeline
When I run it the error is

```
##[warning]An image label with the label vs2017-win2016 does not exist.
,##[error]The remote provider was unable to process the request.
Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: vs2017-win2016
```

I will try

```
vmImage: 'windows-2022'
```

[Update]

I have rolled back and am at the point where I just want to try setting  setting the 'NUGET_ENABLE_LEGACY_CSPROJ_PACK' environment variable to 'true'

[Update]
As per Zar Shardan's advice I updated to use DotNetCoreCLI@2 for the pack.
Then I ran into this error.

> ##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not
> dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet
> build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate
> such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use
> Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk
> version(<=3) to build
> ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
> ##[error]An error occurred while trying to pack the files.

So I tried changing the restore command to

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'WinFormsCoreMain\nuget.config'
    patchVersion: '$(Patch)'
```

Where upon the build started failing with messages like

> ```
>  Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' == '2.0' and ('$(ProjectToolsVersion)' !=
> ```
>
> '2.0' and '$(ProjectToolsVersion)' != '')) was evaluated as ('Current'
> == '2.0' and ('' != '2.0' and '' != '')).

and

> Nuget.Config is not valid XML

and

> ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
> ##[error]Packages failed to restore

I noticed thatDotNetCoreCLI@2 does not support the

```
restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
```

and wonder if my issue has something to do with that.

[Update]

My build YAML is

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

I think this is not working with the more recent dotnetcorecli

[Update]
Trying to use DotNetCoreCLI@2 instead I ran into [new problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75632440/nuget-config-is-not-valid-xml-path-running-dotnetcorecli).

Comment: It's telling you to *not* use the `NugetCommand@2` task, and instead run `dotnet pack`.

Answer (score 8):

Simply replacing NuGetCommand@2 with DotNetCoreCLI@2 solves the original OP's issue:

```
-task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'

...etc...
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question with details about my attempt to do this.

Answer (score 7):

I got it working by adding

```
NUGET_ENABLE_LEGACY_CSPROJ_PACK: true
```

to

```
variables:
```

Answer (score 2):

Nuget pack command is now depreciated. This is working in Nuget version 6.4 but on version 6.5+ an error will be raise when using nuget.exe to pack an SDK.

Nuget Release Notes : [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-6.5Merge)

Merge ticket: [Here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7778)

The recommendation from Nuget is to use the DotNetCLI to pack now instead due the amount of issues that can arise when using the Nuget Pack.

Comment: Gotta love how MS deprecates a tool before the new tool can reproduce all the same functionality.  The current version of dotnet pack will not allow you to override the package version from the command line (using PackageVersion) if you have specified a nuspec file as well.  So currently, the ONLY way to make this happen that I can find is to use nuget.exe pack command.  Also, the dotnet pack has no option to include dependent projects, so if you need that (and I certainly do) then the dotnet pack is neat, but not usable.

Answer (score 0):

Had this to the environment it works

```
$Env:NUGET_ENABLE_LEGACY_CSPROJ_PACK="true"
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the OP’s answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).