# NuGet.Config is not valid XML. Path running DotNetCoreCli

Tags: azure-devops, devexpress, azure-pipelines-yaml

The following task fails in my Azure Devops pipeline.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'WinFormsCoreMain\NuGet.Config'
```

with errors like

```
 "D:\a\1\s\MySnap.Main.sln" (Restore target) (1) ->
       "D:\a\1\s\SBD.Core.MySnap.UI\SBD.Core.MySnap.UI.csproj" (_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry target) (6:6) ->
         C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.200\NuGet.targets(679,5): error : NuGet.Config is not valid XML. Path: 'D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_6479.config'. [D:\a\1\s\SBD.Core.MySnap.UI\SBD.Core.MySnap.UI.csproj]
       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.200\NuGet.targets(679,5): error :   The '@' character, hexadecimal value 0x40, cannot be included in a name. Line 8, position 46. [D:\a\1\s\SBD.Core.MySnap.UI\SBD.Core.MySnap.UI.csproj]
```

WinFormsCoreMain\NuGet.Config exists

The pipeline so far is

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  
  Major: '2'
  Minor: '0'
  Patch: '0'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>=4.3.0'
    checkLatest: false

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'WinFormsCoreMain\NuGet.Config'
```

I upgraded to using DotNetCoreCli@2 after my old pipeline recently [stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75597699/error-nu5049-the-pack-command-for-sdk-style-projects-is-not-supported).

I also upgraded my projects to being either .net7 or framework4.8 figuring the only way out is forward.

[Update]

Investigating advice at [help](https://%20https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps?port=1025&fsid=e8b7eeed-2c5b-4b1f-aef3-95e5979c08b6&viewtype=all&q=NuGet.Config%20is%20not%20valid%20XML.%20Path%20running%20DotNetCoreCli).

> The issue can be fixed using the new NugetAuthenticate task.

[image: Nuget authenticate]

So how do I format the service connection credentials?

I guess I use information from within my Nuget Package Manager -> Packages Sources ?

I tried adding a name

[image: unexpected property]

Now I am checking the [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#nuget-service-connection)

I have updated the steps as follows but there is no improvement

```
steps:
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
  inputs:
    forceReinstallCredentialProvider: true
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>=5.2'
    checkLatest: false

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'WinFormsCoreMain\NuGet.Config'
```

[Update]

NuGet.Config looks like this ( with obfuscations)

[image: Nuget.Config]

Checking [DevExpress advice](https://docs.devexpress.com/GeneralInformation/400604/installation/install-devexpress-controls-using-nuget-packages/integrate-nuget-to-popular-continuous-integration-systems).

[Update[

I tried commenting out the "SBDCommonFeed@Local" packageSource and the restore task was able to run.

SBDCommonFeed is the name of a feed in my artifacts.
Why do I need to comment it out to avoid this particular error?

Comment: It says that your nuget.config doesn't contain valid XML. What does the file actually look like?

Comment: @DanielMann Good point. I updated the question and discovered that the issue is to do with a package source that is an artifact..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the failed build error message:

> NuGet.targets(679,5): error : NuGet.Config is not valid XML. Path: 'D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_6479.config'

> NuGet.targets(679,5): error :   The '@' character, hexadecimal value 0x40, cannot be included in a name

It appears, that some special characters https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7948 (including the "@" one) are not allowed within a name of the "packageSources" of a static and dynamically generated NuGet.config files.

So, if you are allowed to modify the YAML/NuGet.config file(s), try to avoid the "@" char in the package source name(s).